# Knockout.js foreach binding value is not assigning to current object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loop/bwzqs/3/) where i am trying to change value of each foreach binding. If I try to change value of a row then binding updates all other rows which I don't want. what wrong with this binding?

```
<div data-bind="foreach:lines">
<div>
    <input data-bind="value: qty, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
    <label data-bind="text: qty"></label>
</div>
```

```
var Product = function (qty) {
 self = this;
 self.qty = ko.observable(qty);
};
var Cart = function () {
 self = this;
 self.lines = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.lines.push(new Product(1));
 self.lines.push(new Product(2));
};
ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

UPDATE: I moved self.lines.push into cart model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing `var` from `self = this`. It needs to be `var self = this`. In your example, `self` is a global variable and each object is sharing the same `self` value.

Answer (score 0):

Cart is your model:

```
var c  = new Cart();
ko.applyBindings(c);

c.lines.push(new Product(1))
c.lines.push(new Product(2));​

http://jsfiddle.net/gY26k/
```

Comment: don't work. I moved lines.push into cartmodel still don't work. please see my edit.